# Why same data take more space in text file then excel file?

Tags: excel, text, filesize, disk, diskspace

I have data around 100000 rows. If I stored this data in text file format, it takes more space than if I stored it in Excel file format.

Comment: What do these rows consist of? If there are lots of space characters, those still count as a byte in terms of storage, whereas in the Excel document they might get stripped. Can you give us some sample data?

Comment: This might be a question better suited for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) than SO.

Answer (score 2):

Because internally in xslx file data are compressed. They are stored in XML format by later complete file is compressed.

This could be easily checked by changing .xslx extension to .zip and opening by any zip software including Windows Explorer - just double click on it.

So data inside your text file seems to have high compression ratio.